# Mixed models with R - convert from SAS code

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have this SAS code running a mixed model:

```
proc mixed data = Data;
  class Treatment SubjectID Technique;
  model Time = Treatment;
  random Technique;
  random SubjectID(Technique);
  lsmeans Treatment / cl pdiff=control('New') adjust=dunnett;
run;
```

I want to run this analysis in R, what is the equivalent R code ?

Thank you !
(I find the R code for mixed models to be extremely confusing).

Comment: To my knowledge, ```lme``` and ```proc mixed``` use completely different methods, especially if you would write ```type=UN``` in the random statement.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to get the same results in both SAS and R ? It makes no sense, how would I know which one is better than ?

Comment: There are plenty of variance component procedures for mixed models, MINQUE, MIVQUE0, REML, ANOVA etc. Rao wrote some books about this. You can change them by the ```method``` option in the ```proc mixed``` statement. I hope someone else knows more regarding R.

Comment: SAS is using REML by defualt

Comment: I don't understand why you have a first random effect as Technique is also part of your second.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the equivalent R code, using the `lme` package, would be:

```
res <- lme(Time ~ factor(Treatment), random = ~ 1 | Technique/SubjectID, data=Data)
```

As for the `lsmeans` part, you should check the [lsmeans](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/) package.